# How to get the second to last script closing tag using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I need to get the second to last script closing tag using Nokogiri.

Example code:

```
<head>
    <script src="first.js"></script>
    <script src="second.js"></script>
    <!-- How to place some scripts here? -->
    <script>
      // init load
    </script>
</head>
```

I tried code like this `doc.css('/html/head/script')[-2]`. However, it places code inside the tags.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". There's no minimal code sample demonstrating what you want, nor an expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you want because you didn't give us an expected result, but this seems like what you're saying:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="first.js"></script>
        <script src="second.js"></script>
        <!-- How to place some scripts here? -->
        <script>
          // init load
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
EOT

doc.css('script')[-2].add_next_sibling("\n<script src='new_script.js'></script>")
```

Which results in:

```
doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
#    "<html>\n" +
#    "    <head>\n" +
#    "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n" +
#    "        <script src=\"first.js\"></script>\n" +
#    "        <script src=\"second.js\"></script>\n" +
#    "<script src=\"new_script.js\"></script>\n" +
#    "        <!-- How to place some scripts here? -->\n" +
#    "        <script>\n" +
#    "          // init load\n" +
#    "        </script>\n" +
#    "    </head>\n" +
#    "</html>\n"
```

Nokogiri's [XML::Node documentation](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#add_previous_sibling-instance_method) is full of useful methods. I'd recommend reading it *many* times.

Nokogiri doesn't know about closing tags. After parsing it knows there's an object and that object has siblings in the hierarchy, so we can search for the objects and then, in this case, insert a new node. If you ask it to output the HTML, then based on the rules for HTML it will supply closing tags, even if they were not there in the first place.